# div class fades in page on load

Tags: css, class, fadein, onload

I would like to have different classes fade in on page load.

See [this web page](http://www.humphrey-ray.com/pct/demo8b.html).

As you see in the link above there are a number of squares in different shades of grey and some in color.

I would like to fade in the squares at different delays. I have found several articles and post on fading in ID tags but none to fade in Class tags. I could do it by ID but it would mean targeting each square since ID's can only effect one element.

I would like to effects several squares at time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use data attributes, like `data-start-color="#CCCCCC"`, `data-end-color`, `data-over-time="100"`, `data-out-time`.

Then you could use one function for all squares. Something like that (sorry, I didn't check it on your page):

```
$('.square').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: $(this).data('end-color') }, $(this).data('over-time'));
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: $(this).data('start-color') }, $(this).data('out-time'));
  }
)
```